# React does not recognize the prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, dom, conditional-operator

This is my code
Whenever I add this condition of `IsTermsAndConditionsEnabled` in my code it gives error for some properties fmoId , isDefault and isAdmin.

IsTermsAndConditionsEnabled is coming in props

Warning is

act_devtools_backend.js:2655 Warning: React does not recognize the `isDefault` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `isdefault` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

```
                   ` {IsTermsAndConditionsEnabled  ? 
                        <>
                             <DateInput
                                id="PublishDate"
                                label="Publish date"
                                fmoId={fmoId}
                                isDefault={isDefault}
                                isAdmin={isAdmin}
                                defaultValue={defaultValues && defaultValues.PublishDate.value}
                                textValue={selectedFmoValues && selectedValues.PublishDate.value}
                                resourceId={selectedFmoValues && selectedValues.PublishDate.resourceId}
                            />

                            <Editor
                                id="SomeId"
                                label="Some Label"
                            />
                        </>
                : <span></span> }`
```

This is DateInput Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { InputLabel, InputBase } from "@material-ui/core";
import LightToolTip from "./../LightToolTip";

const DateInput = ({
    id,
    label,
    fmoId,
    isDefault,
    isAdmin,
    defaultValue,
    textValue,
    resourceId,
    updateParentValue,
}) => {
    
    const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");
    const today = new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setInputVal(textValue || "")
    }, [fmoId, textValue]);

    const updateInputVal = (value) => {
        const calendarDate = new Date(value).setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
        if (calendarDate >= today) {
            setInputVal(value);
            updateParentValue(id, value, resourceId, false);
        }
    };

    function getValidFormat(inputDate) {
        const trimedDate = inputDate.trim();
        if (trimedDate.length > 0) {
            const inputDate = new Date(trimedDate);
            const year = inputDate.getFullYear();
            const month = String(inputDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
            const day = String(inputDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
            const formattedDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
            return formattedDate;
        }
        return "";
    }
   
    return (
        <>
            <LightToolTip
                title={!isAdmin ? "" : `Key: ${id}`}>
                <InputLabel htmlFor={id}>
                     {label}
                </InputLabel>
            </LightToolTip>

      { !isDefault ? (
                <LightToolTip
                    title={`Default: ${defaultValue || "No Default Found"}`}>
                    <InputBase
                        type="date"
                        min={today}
                        fullWidth={true}
                        id={id}
                        name={id}
                        value={getValidFormat(inputVal)}
                        onChange={(e) => updateInputVal(e.target.value)} 
                    />
                </LightToolTip>
      )
      :
                <InputBase
                    type="date"
                    min={today}
                    fullWidth={true}
                    id={id}
                    name={id}
                    value={getValidFormat(inputVal)}
                    onChange={(e) => updateInputVal(e.target.value)} 
                />
      }
     
    </>
    );
};
export default DateInput;
```

I have tried

1.Using && operator but it does not works

2.If I remove this condition based code it works fine

Comment: You'll need to show the implementation for `DateInput` too – that's the component causing the actual issue here.

Comment: Check now , I have added the date code

Comment: Feels a bit like `<DateInput>` is instantiating a different component to the one you're expecting. What happens if you (temporarily!) copy the `DateInput` implementation you have here into the same file that you're using it from?

Comment: I have added exact code now , please have a look again